# Add a separator every 3 item in flatlist - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, separator, flatlist

How can I add a separator for every 3 items in flatlist? I can just add a separator after every 1 item. I did not find a prop for that. Here are my codes:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Item 1',
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Item 2',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Item 3',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: ' Item 4',
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Item 5',
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Item 6',
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        title: 'Item 7',
    },
];


const App = () => {

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
    );

    const seperator = () => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.seperator} />
        )
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={DATA}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(items) => items.id}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={seperator}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    item: {
        backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
        padding: 10,
        marginVertical: 8,
        marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 32,
    },
    seperator: {
        width: 300,
        height: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
});

export default App;
```

My app looks likes:

[image]

But I want to make that:

[image]

How can I add a separator for every 3 items in flatlist? I can just add a separator after every 1 item. I did not find a prop for that.

Comment: Haven't tested but can try this logic. In the Item constant -- You check whether the item is the third (`item.id %3 === 0`)and then call the separator function in the `renderItem` function itself.

Comment: Got Fizz Buzz??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case your data items do not have an *id* or a property that can easily distinguish two items, consider using a counter to keep track of how many times your `separator` function was called.

However, it is important to work with some key in `keyExtractor`, because it is used for caching and as the react key to track item re-ordering.

For this case, anyways, [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook can be used, since:

> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument

Note that it would still be doable if you've chosen *useState* hook instead, but probably more verbose.

```js
import { useRef } from 'react' 

let count = useRef(0)
const seperator = (e) => {
        count.current += 1
        return (
          (count.current % 3 == 0) ? <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                                   : null
       )
}

return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={DATA}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={(e) => seperator(e)}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
)
```

Since it's mutable, add one unit each time the function is called

Answer (score 3):

First, pass an arrow function receiving an argument. In this case, it's `e`, which holds the object (for instance the first):

> `{"highlighted":false,"leadingItem":{"id":1,"title":"Item 1"}}`

So it's an easy approach, get the id and check if its `%3 === 0`. Take a look:

```
 const seperator = (e) => {
        return (
          (e.leadingItem.id % 3 == 0) ? <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                                      : null

        )
    }
```

And then

```
return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={DATA}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(items) => items.id}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={(e) => seperator(e)}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

As you can see in this working [example](https://snack.expo.dev/5PGBZz3kl)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Well how can I do that if my data items do not have id?